# how do i change background that is an image through admin button in html tailwind css

Tags: html, image, file-upload, tailwind-css, background-image

So below is the code it seems to run ok but i can't see the background image on website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dynamic Wallpaper Change</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- Main body div start -->
  <body>
    <!-- Header div Start -->
    <div class="bg-gray-800 text-white p-4">
      <!-- Admin Button -->
      <button
        class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded"
        onclick="showImageForm()"
      >
        Admin
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Header div end -->
    <!-- Body div start -->
    <div id="bodyContainer"></div>
    <!-- Body div end -->
    <!-- Footer div start -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- Footer div end -->

    <!-- Image Upload Form -->
    <!-- Image Upload Form -->
    <div
      id="imageFormContainer"
      class="hidden fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75"
    >
      <form id="imageForm" class="p-8 bg-white max-w-md mx-auto mt-16 rounded">
        <label for="imageInput" class="block mb-4 text-lg font-semibold"
          >Upload Image:</label
        >
        <input type="file" id="imageInput" class="mb-4" accept="image/*" />
        <button
          type="button"
          onclick="changeBackground()"
          class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded"
        >
          Change Background
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          onclick="hideImageForm()"
          class="bg-gray-500 text-white px-4 py-2 ml-4 rounded"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Function to show the image upload form
      function showImageForm() {
        document
          .getElementById("imageFormContainer")
          .classList.remove("hidden");
      }

      // Function to hide the image upload form
      function hideImageForm() {
        document.getElementById("imageFormContainer").classList.add("hidden");
      }

      // Function to change the background dynamically
      function changeBackground() {
        const fileInput = document.getElementById("imageInput");
        const bodyContainer = document.getElementById("bodyContainer");

        if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
          const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
          bodyContainer.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imageURL}')`;
          bodyContainer.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
          bodyContainer.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
          bodyContainer.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
        }

        hideImageForm();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  <!-- Main body div end -->
</html>
```

i tried the above code again and again but can't see the image i dont know whats wrong. Please help me out i dont know what to do onward.i am really looking forward to solving this problem by the help of you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is consistent, the only issue I found was that the "bodyContainer" div has height equal to zero

if you change the tag as follows:

```
<div id="bodyContainer" class="h-screen"></div>
```

it resolves the issue

Please do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if it meets your requirements

Answer (score 0):

the above js code is working fine but the problem is that height of div with class bodyContainer is 0 , add height to this class other that 0 such as 500px to make it work

Comment: thank you so much its working as intended thank you so much..although i refresh the page and it goes away.so i have to make it permanent other than that its working fine

Comment: add static style in that div -> <div id="bodyContainer" style="height: 500px" ></div>, also mark this ans correct if it satisfies your need !